# simplexml_load_string throws Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to convert the below XML string into an XML object with simplexml_load_string() but it always throws the error 'Notice: Array to string conversion' and I cannot find the reason why.

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tns:PrintParcelResponse xmlns:tns="http://example.com/xox">
  <tns:ExitStatus>
    <tns:Status>Success</tns:Status>
    <tns:StatusDetails>
      <tns:StatusDetail>
        <tns:Status>Success</tns:Status>
        <tns:Code>0</tns:Code>
        <tns:Message>Succeed</tns:Message>
        <tns:Details></tns:Details>
      </tns:StatusDetail>
    </tns:StatusDetails>
  </tns:ExitStatus>
  <tns:OutputParameters>
    <tns:ShippingParameter>
      <tns:Name>Shipment.Identcode</tns:Name>
      <tns:Value>123</tns:Value>
    </tns:ShippingParameter>
    <tns:ShippingParameter>
      <tns:Name>Parcel.Identcode</tns:Name>
      <tns:Value>123</tns:Value>
    </tns:ShippingParameter>
    <tns:ShippingParameter>
      <tns:Name>Shipment.Retoure</tns:Name>
      <tns:Value>444</tns:Value>
    </tns:ShippingParameter>
    <tns:ShippingParameter>
      <tns:Name>Shipment.LabelName</tns:Name>
      <tns:Value>5455555</tns:Value>
    </tns:ShippingParameter>
    <tns:ShippingParameter>
      <tns:Name>Shipment.LabelName</tns:Name>
      <tns:Value>4356467465</tns:Value>
    </tns:ShippingParameter>
    <tns:ShippingParameter>
      <tns:Name>Shipment.Status</tns:Name>
      <tns:Value>Created|Printed</tns:Value>
    </tns:ShippingParameter>
  </tns:OutputParameters>
</tns:PrintParcelResponse>
EOF;

$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$errors = libxml_get_errors();

foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo display_xml_error($error, $xml);
}

libxml_clear_errors();

print_r($xml_object);
```

UPDATE

I have changed it based on the comment but now it just returns

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

and not the array. What am I missing now?

Comment: [`libxml_get_errors()`](https://www.php.net/libxml_get_errors) returns an array. You're passing it to `die()`, which expects a string.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question with the correct syntax but now I don't get an array back.

Comment: I suggest edit your title to reflect your new problem

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with that, when you print_r the xml object, it's empty because you use namespace in your xml. So you need to specify your namespace when you try loading the xml string like this

```
$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA, "http://example.com/xox");
```

So when you print_r your object, it's going to look like this

```
print_r((array)$xml_object);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ExitStatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Status] => Success
            [StatusDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [StatusDetail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Status] => Success
                            [Code] => 0
                            [Message] => Succeed
                            [Details] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [OutputParameters] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ShippingParameter] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Shipment.Identcode
                            [Value] => 123
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Parcel.Identcode
                            [Value] => 123
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Shipment.Retoure
                            [Value] => 444
                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Shipment.LabelName
                            [Value] => 5455555
                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Shipment.LabelName
                            [Value] => 4356467465
                        )

                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Shipment.Status
                            [Value] => Created|Printed
                        )

                )

        )

)
```